# java quaternion 3D rotation implementation

Tags: java, math, 3d

Now the rotation works, i've tried rotating an object by 90 degrees, it rotates it but also makes an unexpected translation on the oX axis to the left. I've added a normalisation mehod for w,x,y,z components of the quaterion and corrected any code mistakes i found.

This is the method i use:

```
 public class Point3DRotationQuaternions 
  {
   public static ArrayList<Float> rotation3D(ArrayList<Float> points, double angle, int x, int y, int z)
   {
    ArrayList<Float> newpoints = points;

    for (int i=0;i<points.size();i+=3)
    {
        float x_old = points.get(i).floatValue();
        float y_old = points.get(i+1).floatValue();
        float z_old = points.get(i+2).floatValue();
        double[] initial = {1,0,0,0};
        double[] total = new double[4];
        double[] local = new double[4];

        //components for local quaternion
        //w
        local[0] = Math.cos(0.5 * angle);
        //x
        local[1] = x * Math.sin(0.5 * angle);
        //y
        local[2] = y * Math.sin(0.5 * angle);
        //z
        local[3] = z * Math.sin(0.5 * angle);
        //local = magnitude(local);

        //components for final quaternion Q1*Q2
        //w = w1w2 - x1x2 - y1y2 - z1z2
        total[0] = local[0] * initial[0] - local[1] * initial[1] - local[2] * initial[2] - local[3] * initial[3];
        //x = w1x2 + x1w2 + y1z2 - z1y2
        total[1] = local[0] * initial[1] + local[1] * initial[0] + local[2] * initial[3] - local[3] * initial[2];
        //y = w1y2 - x1z2 + y1w2 + z1x2
        total[2] = local[0] * initial[2] - local[1] * initial[3] + local[2] * initial[0] + local[3] * initial[1];
        //z = w1z2 + x1y2 - y1x2 + z1w2
        total[3] = local[0] * initial[3] + local[1] * initial[2] - local[2] * initial[1] + local[3] * initial[0];

        //new x,y,z of the 3d point using rotation matrix made from the final quaternion
        float x_new = (float)((1 - 2 * total[2] * total[2] - 2 * total[3] * total[3]) * x_old
                         + (2 * total[1] * total[2] - 2 * total[0] * total[3]) * y_old
                         + (2 * total[1] * total[3] + 2 * total[0] * total[2]) * z_old);
        float y_new = (float) ((2 * total[1] * total[2] + 2 * total[0] * total[3]) * x_old
                         + (1 - 2 * total[1] * total[1] - 2 * total[3] * total[3]) * y_old
                         + (2 * total[2] * total[3] + 2 * total[0] * total[1]) * z_old);
        float z_new = (float) ((2 * total[1] * total[3] - 2 * total[0] * total[2]) * x_old
                         + (2 * total[2] * total[3] - 2 * total[0] * total[1]) * y_old
                         + (1 - 2 * total[1] * total[1] - 2 * total[2] * total[2]) * z_old);
        newpoints.set(i, x_new);
        newpoints.set(i+1, y_new);
        newpoints.set(i+2, z_new);

    }

    return newpoints;
  }
}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{

    ArrayList<Float> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Float(0));
    list.add(new Float(0));
    list.add(new Float(-11));
    ArrayList<Float> list1 = Point3DRotationQuaternions.rotation3D(list, Math.toRadians(90), 0, 1, 0);
    for (int i=0;i<list1.size();i++)
        System.out.print(list1.get(i)+" ");
}
```

Now the call looks like this `rotation3D(points, Math.toRadians(90), 0, 1, 0)`. 
To write these methods i used [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html) .

These are the vertexes for the figure i try to rotate:

//bottom base

old vertexes:

0.0 0.0 -9.0

0.0 0.0 -11.0

20.0 0.0 -11.0

20.0 0.0 -9.0

new vertexes:

-9.0 0.0 -1.9984014E-15

-11.0 0.0 -2.4424907E-15

-11.0 0.0 -20.0

-9.0 0.0 -20.0

//top base

old vertexes:

0.0 20.0 -11.0

0.0 20.0 -9.0

20.0 20.0 -9.0

20.0 20.0 -11.0

new vertexes:

-11.0 20.0 -2.4424907E-15

-9.0 20.0 -1.9984014E-15

-9.0 20.0 -20.0

-11.0 20.0 -20.0

//face

old vertexes:

0.0 20.0 -9.0

0.0 0.0 -9.0

20.0 0.0 -9.0

20.0 20.0 -9.0

new vertexes:

-9.0 20.0 -1.9984014E-15

-9.0 0.0 -1.9984014E-15

-9.0 0.0 -20.0

-9.0 20.0 -20.0

//back

old vertexes:

20.0 20.0 -9.0

20.0 0.0 -9.0

20.0 0.0 -11.0

20.0 20.0 -11.0

new vertexes:
-9.0 20.0 -20.0

-9.0 0.0 -20.0

-11.0 0.0 -20.0

-11.0 20.0 -20.0

//right side

old vertexes:

0.0 0.0 -11.0

0.0 20.0 -11.0

20.0 20.0 -11.0

20.0 0.0 -11.0

new vertexes:

-11.0 0.0 -2.4424907E-15

-11.0 20.0 -2.4424907E-15

-11.0 20.0 -20.0

-11.0 0.0 -20.0

//left base

old vertexes:

0.0 20.0 -9.0

0.0 20.0 -11.0

0.0 0.0 -11.0

0.0 0.0 -9.0

new vertexes:

-9.0 20.0 -1.9984014E-15

-11.0 20.0 -2.4424907E-15

-11.0 0.0 -2.4424907E-15

-9.0 0.0 -1.9984014E-15

Comment: You're sure you want a rotation of 50 radians? Or do you want degrees?

Comment: The `Math` functions take angles in radians, not degrees. You can convert via `Math.toRadians()`.

Comment: @StefanHanke i corrected my code following your instructions. I've still got a problem as described in the edited post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide sample points where you think it is not correct. And remove that optimization in `magnitude`...

Comment: Now where exactly you think is anything wrong? Pick one point and its transformee, and try to explain :)

Comment: i would really like to know where the problem is, but i don't. it makes the rotation the right way, but at the same time the figure is translated on the oX axis to the right. And even more, the new vertexes go from an -11 to -2.4424907E-15 . that can't be good, when the angle is 90 degrees, should be -2.0 or -2.5...am i right?

Comment: Taken the point `P=(0,0,-11)`, the rotation of `90°` around the y-axis yields `P_R=(-11, 0, 0)`. The `E` notation is called [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), and these values can safely be rounded to `0`. Perhaps best you try to visualize the rotations in 2D first, and using linear algebra.

Comment: well, if i try with a list of 3 coordinates (0,0,-11) for a rotation of 90° , my method returns (-9.833963 0.0 4.9288096) so there must be something wrong with my math.

Comment: To make sure, I copy/pasted your code into a sample project, and unfortunately I cannot reproduce your results. I didn't check the code, though...

Comment: What do you mean by "i cannot reproduce your results"? the output is different?

Comment: This means that I am not able to get the same output as you. The output looks correct. Please add the full source in your question, with the one point `P=(0,0,-11)` transformed, so I can run the exact same code.

Comment: I added the main class, and completed the rotation class where the `rotation3D` method is written.

Comment: OK, again, copypasted your code, fixed typos, the output is `-11.0 0.0 -2.4424907E-15`. The only thing is that you're using Java 1.7 (because of the missing type parameter when creating the `ArrayList`), I have installed version 1.6.

Comment: well, after reading a little more about quaternion rotations i realised that the rotation is made about the center of the system, this why i thought my object is misplaced...so there is no mistake afterall...i just need to make a translation now, or use a transformation matrix, not just a rotation matrix. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your welcome, and glad to hear that. FYI There are more matrices that treat the origin special; all [linear maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_transformation) do. OK, enough commented :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing `total[0] = ...` four times.

Comment: I corrected that, it rotates but it also makes an unwanted translation.